# Uniqueness of additive inverse

Tags: real-analysis

Using only these properties:

A1. $x + (y+z) = (x+y) + z$
A2. $x + y = y + x$
A3. There is an
integer zero such that $x + 0 = x$
A4. To each integer $x$ there
corresponds an integer $(-x)$ such that $x+(-x)=0$

Show that given $x$, $(-x)$ is unique based on A1-A4

So far I've gotten

- Assume A1-A4, $y=-x$, $z=-x$, and $y \neq z$
- For all $x$: $x+y = 0$ based on A4
- For all $x$: $x+z = 0$ based on A4
- If $x=z$, $z+y = 0$
- If $x=y$, $y+z = 0$
  However, I'm stuck from here, any tips on how to continue the proof?

Comment: consider the two ways of evaluating $z+x+y$!

Comment: Hi Gordofreemo! Just letting you know that the real-analysis tag on this question doesn't seem to be very accurate. Perhaps abstract-algebra or group-theory is more appropriate? The assumptions stated are consistent with that of a commuative group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x$ has two inverses, $-x$ and $(-x) + y$ where $y\neq 0$. Then,

$x+((-x)+y) =0$

must hold. By A1, we have

$x+((-x)+y) = (x+(-x)) +y = 0 + y =y \neq 0$

which is a contradiction

$\implies y=0$

or, $(-x) + y = (-x)$ is the single unique inverse of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ both be additive inverses of $x$. This means that

$x+x_{1}=0$ ---(1)

and

$x+x_{2}=0$ ---(2).

By pre-adding $x_{2}$ to (1),

$x_{2}+(x+x_{1})=x_{2}+0$

$(x_{2}+x)+x_{1}=x_{2}$ (by A1)

$(x+x_{2})+x_{1}=x_{2}$ (by A2)

$0+x_{1}=x_{2}$ (by A4)

$x_{1}+0=x_{2}$ (by A2)

$x_{1}=x_{2}$ (by A3) as desired